# Chain rule (multivariate) and implicit differentiation problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule, implicit-differentiation, change-of-variable

I have been worked out a solution for the following problem, but I am wondering if there is an **easier** way to solve it. I would be very grateful for any suggestions!

> Let $z=f(x,y)$ a function of two independent variables $x$. and $y$. Show that, if we perform a change of variables with $u$ and $v$ $u=x^2+y^2$ and $u=e^{\frac{y}{x}}$, then $$x \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = 2v \frac{\partial z}{\partial v} \:.$$

**My solution:**
By the multivariate chain rule, we have
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}
\:.$$
Hence it is sufficient to show that $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{x}{2v}$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial v} = \frac{y}{2v}$. There are two ways in which we can do this (I will consider only $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$):

- Either we calculate the partial derivatives$\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$, $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and use the fact that, by the [inverse function rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_rule),
  $$
  \begin{bmatrix}
      \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} \\
      \frac{\partial y}{\partial v} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
      \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \\
      \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}
  \end{bmatrix}^{-1}
  $$
  to obtain
  $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}} = \frac{x}{2v}
  .$$
- Or we simply notice that $\ln(u) = \frac{y}{x}$ and thus $y = x \cdot \ln(u)$. Substituting this into $v=x^2+y^2$, we get $x^2=\frac{v}{1+[\ln(u)]^2}$ and, if we partially differentiate both sides with respect to $v$, we obtain $2x\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{1+[\ln(u)]^2} = \frac{1}{1+\left[\frac{y}{x}\right]^2} = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x^2}{v}$, as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to calculate

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial(x^2+y^2)} = \frac{\partial x}{\partial \left(x^2\cdot\left(1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right)\right)}$$

Why does this rewrite matter? Because implicitly, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$ means we are taking the derivative of $x$ with respect $v$, *while $u$ is held constant*. If $u$ is constant, then so is the right resultant expression in the denominator meaning we can pull it out of the derivative

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} = \frac{1}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\frac{\partial(x^2)}{\partial x}} = \frac{x}{2(x^2+y^2)} \equiv \frac{x}{2v}$$

where we used the inverse function rule in the second step because we were left with only a single variable expression.